# REST API Consecutive Call is not working

Tags: c#, rest

**SOLVED**

The problem was sending the number with double quotes like "40".
So I replaced quotes with empty space and It worked.
This is the code.

HRMID = HRMID.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();

---

I am trying to call my REST service consecutively but only one of them is working when I do that.
If I call only one of them in one block it works but two of them in one function block is causing problems I think,I don't know why.
Maybe it is something about restriction in the service.
There is no Error just it is not updating the Database.
If I use it alone it works so call is correct.
This is my code , I am waiting for suggestions.

Thanks!

```
    private void GameClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do your stuff when the game closed.
        try
        {             

            var client = new WebClient();

            var result = client.DownloadString(wsUrl + "/rest/gethrmid/" + UserValues[4]);// Only the first REST API call is working.This one works.

            MessageBox.Show("Result is :" + result);




            string HRMID = result;

            StreamReader SR = new StreamReader("D:/HRMSession.txt");
            string hrmValues = SR.ReadToEnd();               

            client.DownloadString(wsUrl + "/rest/inserthrmsession/" + HRMID + "/" + hrmValues);//This one is not working if i put here.


        }
        catch (Exception a)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
        }

    }
```

EDIT:
If I write it as hardcoded it works but if I use the value that is coming from first call it doesn't work.

```
     client.DownloadString(wsUrl + "/rest/inserthrmsession/" + 40 + "/" + hrmValues);//Works.
```

But I can not convert the value of HRMID to Int because operation contract is string...

Comment: Can u add this line before the second download string call  client = new WebClient(); ?

Comment: @AbdulRehmanSayed I did it again but still no luck.

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: @AbdulRehmanSayed No error still first call is working and the second one does nothing again.It should have updated the database but it is not calling

Comment: @AbdulRehmanSayed The problem is if I write HRMID directly 40 it works.But if first call returns it and If i use it it doesn't work it's so weird.Trying to solve that thing now

Comment: Can you check value of HRMID? It may happen, rest api has some spaces or other special char in response. Other option is to cross check response is valid using Int32.TryParse(result, out intHRMID);

Comment: What is the value of HRMID that is working? What is the value that isn't working? If you debug the REST service, does it call the function that updates the database for either / or / both of those HRMID values?

Comment: @mjwills If I write just 40 there it works but if that 40 comes from the rest api call it doesn't.It returns just "40" value nothing more.I think it must have call that functions because just 40 is working.

Comment: @Kaushal There is no special char in response.Just "40" that's all.I don't understand how can I take benefit from that function ?

Comment: Add `client.Dispose()` or add `using(client = new WebClient())` same for `StreamReader`

Comment: @Max Thanks for reply but It didn't work too.As my progress ,It's about the input of the rest call.I have to write it hard coded not as variable I don't know why.

Comment: Try use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to log calls

Comment: @Max Thanks it's been so helpful.It's about extra characters in the response which didn't showed by Message Box.It sends as a %2249%22 , not just 49.

Comment: Glad to help you

Comment: @Max Thank you Max.Have a good day.